# Link .lib library using codeblocks

Tags: c++, c, codeblocks, .lib

I tried to link a .lib library in a C++ project using codeblocks but i got a lot of erros like :

```
undefined reference to `_RTC_CheckEsp'
undefined reference to `_RTC_Shutdown'
undefined reference to `_RTC_InitBase'
undefined reference to `_RTC_CheckEsp'
undefined reference to `_RTC_CheckEsp'
```

What should i do to correct this errors ?

Comment: Have you tried google?

Comment: Which compiler are you using?

Comment: I searched a lot but i didn't find any solution. I use Mingw compiler . (On windows 7 32 bit )

Comment: Take a look [HERE](http://www.qtcentre.org/archive/index.php/t-6706.html)